# saving list of value objects in table

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have similar scenario in [Domain Driven Design Question on Services and Repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142536/domain-driven-design-question-on-services-and-repositories) and http://pastie.org/795679 which the azamsharp faces.

Since registration is value object, and user can have list of value objects, how can i save this registrations in user table because there is 1 to M relationship between User and Registration. Do i have to create seperate table for registration.

Answer (score 0):

DDD or no DDD, it you have a 1-M relationship, the cleanest solution is a separate `Registration` table, with an FK back to the `User`.

Just because `Registrations` are Value objects, doesn't mean that you **have** to save them in the `User` table.  It's a common misconception with DDD newbies.  Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679005/how-are-value-objects-stored-in-the-database/681106#681106) can help.

Comment: Thanks Vijay , but do my Registration table can have ID acting as surrogate key , or only foreign key pointing to User table because this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949320/ddd-value-objects-and-orm says we should not have ID in value object table

Comment: That answer only applies if you have a fixed number of Value Objects.  Your 'Registration' definitely needs an FK back to the 'User'.  A surrogate key is optional (you might need one as your requirements evolve).